# Correct Schema design for following application

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB, Express, React etc and am putting together a simple application to do so but am stuck on the schema design.

The application will be a money manager where users will be able to sign up, then fill in their monthly income (salary and any other income), and regular expenditure. This will provide an amount they are able to spend each month.
The user can then enter transactions throughout the month, the application will log these, which will deplete the monthly allowance to provide the user with a snapshot of their funds available to spend.

I am just stuck on how to structure the schema.

Do I have a separate database for `users`, `expenditure` and `income`, and associate the expenditure and income with the `user` via the user's `_id` value?

Or should the expenditure and income be tracked in the same database as the user?

Comment: As written, this question is off-topic, as it's fairly broad and opinion-soliciting. There's no right answer to this (except... I think you might have meant *collections* instead of *databases* in MongoDB terms). There are many ways to model this data. And the notion of "tracking" is pretty broad as well. A great discussion to be had, but unfortunately this doesn't fit on StackOverflow - too broad, too many possibilities.

Comment: Understood, thanks David. Any ideas where I could repost to get some advice? Yes, sorry I meant collection, not database.